# A small doubt about slopes.

Tags: calculus, kinematics

In velocity vs time graph, the slope would be the acceleration. But if the slope doesn't exist ( the slope from the left doesn't equal the slope from the right ) what would the acceleration be? and what would be the ideal description for that movement?

by description

1. a=+ , v=+ the object is speeding up in the positive value
2. a=- , v=- the object is speeding up in the negative value
3. a=- , v=+ the object is speeding down in the positive value
4. a=+ , v=- the object is speeding down in the negative value
5. a=0 , v=+ the object is moving in constant speed in the positive value
6. a=0 , v=- the object is moving in constant speed in the negative value
7. a=? , v=+ ????????????????????????????????????
8. a=? , v=- ????????????????????????????????????

an example

[image: an example]

t=4, t=7, t=23, t=25, t=27

Comment: Graph theory is something [quite different.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_theory)

Comment: By definition, the acceleration at that time is the slope of the tangent line at the corresponding point. Since that tangent line doesn't exist, neither does the acceleration.

Comment: Take for example the function $f(x)=x^2$, the slope of $f(1)$ and of $f(3)$ are different and yet the slope still exists for these points. The slope is uniform for linear functions (eg: $f(x)=x$) but it's not uniform for a lot of other kinds of functions. Perhaps you're confusing it with the idea of existence of the limit.

Comment: @Calculus No need for that. He probably still doesn't know the rules of the place.

Comment: @Vÿska I'm sorry English is not my "mother" language, about my question, I'll give you an example, a car was accelerating for 5 sec then it decelerated.. at t=5sec, the slope does not exist. Does that mean the slope doesn't exist too? and what is the description of the movement at t=5?

Comment: @Calculus I didn't try to offend you ,nor did I order you. It was a request.

Comment: @Travis thanks very much, what's about the description? can you please tell me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but if the one-sided limits both exist, we can say that the (velocity) function has a *jump discontinuity*.

Comment: @Travis a=+, v=+ , the object is speeding up. a=-, v=- the object is speeding up, a=+ , v=- the object is speeding down, a=-, v=+ the object is speeding down, a=0, v=+ or v=- the object is moving in constant speed..... a=DNE, v=+ or v=- how the object would move? thanks in advance

Comment: _____/ an example or   http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-U8aR2qxNAVI/UVYGp2YqSvI/AAAAAAAAB1E/z1oG0fNnTQw/s1600/velocity+vs+time+graph.png    in t=2 for instance

Comment: @Joe You should edit your original post to include these new questions, being as specific as possible.

Comment: @Travis done editing